# Can we apply CZT after FFT?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals

I want to improve the frequency resolution of the FFT algorithm.
Can the CZT (Chirp z transform) improve resolution if used after the FFT? Because I read in some articles that the CZT has better frequency resolution than the FFT but it is computationally more expensive.

So, if I use the FFT first and then the CZT, will it help improve the frequency resolution?

Answer (score 0):

the FFT is an implementation of the DFT, which is a special case of the CZT. So, no, doing an FFT first and then another CZT will not work – it will take you back into something "time-domain-y".

You're probably just looking for other frequency estimators than the DFT, if you have knowledge about signal structure that allows you to take advantage of other CZTs.

So, I'd recommend asking a new question about your actual spectral estimation problem, describing why you think the CZT is an appropriate method here, and what you actually want to do!

Comment: I am currently working on weak pulsars signal, where i want to improve the frequency resolution of my signal, so i take the FFT of my signal, but the frequency resolution is not good so to improve the frequency resolution of  my FFT i need a technique which can increase the frequency resolution. I tried padding and interpolation, but results is not promising.

Comment: @Tariq: what exactly are you trying to do? Determining the frequency of a signal with high precision or distinguishing two or more signal that are very close in frequency?

Comment: yes, sounds like the FFT might simply not be the tool of choice. A different CZT *instead of* the FFT might work, but as far as I understand pulsars have relatively narrowband spectrum, you might want to use a significant amount of filtering to select bands, and then do a parametric estimation on these – after all, you're looking for exactly one tone. Maybe also talk to the radioastronomy buffs in https://chat.gnuradio.org/#/room/#radioastronomy:gnuradio.org

Comment: @Hilmar my goal is to find the period of a weak signal, for this i need higher frequency resolution.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, you are right. But FFT is widely used algorithm for pulsars, so i tried to use ZCT, but it is computational expensive more than FFT.

Comment: What about Zoom FFT ?

Comment: @AlanCampbell A Zoom FFT is a specific case of the CZT. A Zoom FFT essentially does a frequency shift, low pass filters and decimates. You end up with fewer samples at a lower sampling rate, but the signal has the same time extent. You won't achieve any better frequency resolution - you just get to use a smaller FFT i.e. you save some computations.